# DB - How to save multiple Versions of the same File?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, database-design

I have to save multiple Versions of the same File.
I would like to know how to represent this in the database and if I have to configure something in EF Core for that.

Basically, the User uploads a File and afterwards it´s possible to upload a new Version of this File. Only the newest File shall be shown to the User in Standard View, but it should be possible to see the other Versions. Versions can be deleted. A File has Actions, which say what can be done with this.
How should I write the Model for this?

```
public File{
  public string FileName;
  public int Version;
  public bool Active;
 //+ Actions, that is same for every Version
}
```

1.) I thought that I could just add a List to this class/table, but my problem is what happens if the first Version will be deleted? I would have to always remember to switch the Files.
Also, with this a Version could have Versions, but that´s not correct as they all belong together.

2.) I could just add an `public File ParentFile` and every Version links to the first File. But then I will have again problems with deletion.

3.) Introduce something like a `SameFIleID` Then I would add a List of this ID to the `Project` table, search all the Files with this ID and then take the one with `Active` or highest `Version`.... But then I will have a problem with my `Actions` since I would have to always update all Versions for that instead of just one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just keep the File Definition and the File Contents separate?

```
public class File
{
  public string FileName { get; set; }
  public List<FileContents> Versions { get; set; } = new List<FileContents>();
  
  [NotMapped]
  public FileContents ActiveContents =>
        Versions.OrderByDescending(v => v.Version).FirstOrDefault();
  
  //Actions, that is same for every Version
}

public class FileContents
{
    public File FileDefinition { get; set; }

    public int Version { get; set; }

    // Actual Contents
}
```

This way Actions are only saved once per file. The `ActiveContents` Property will always take the latest version if it exists. This is set as `[NotMapped]` because the active version is implicit in the Version Id and doesn't need to be saved in the database.